# Reporting Services can't completely hide column in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to accomplish this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/08/30/greenbarmatrix.aspx

and am successful all the way to step 6 where I cant get the column to disappear completely. I set all the values explained in the article but when I set the width of the column to 0 it defaults to like `0.3in` and I get this gap that is tiny but large enough to notice.

What can I do to completely hide it?

Comment: Did you define the type, being `0in` in your case? Also make sure the TextBox inside doesn't have a size or padding.

Comment: Yes. It defaults to exactly 0.03125in. Yes I removed the column header, that leaves only the expression that prints to the cell for each row (which aren't shown cause the columns Hidden property is set to false) and it doesn't have a width property

Comment: When you say "Hidden" is set to false, do you mean the `ColumnVisibility` property is set to false? Because surely you'd want hidden to be true, make sure you're changing the right property as the naming is different. You could use the designer and select" Hide" there to be certain.Maybe have al ook at [this](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/3/5/dealing-with-white-space-due-to-a-hidden-textbox-in-reportin.html)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I meant that I have put the Hidden property to True of course.

Comment: Well if the hidden property is set to true then the column shouldn't be seen at all and it is irrelevant that is still has a nominal with of 0.3in. If it is hidden yet still leaving white space, it's not actually being hidden and you need to check the calculation that is setting the hide property

Comment: It's also possible that the column seems visible in the designer but after building it shouldn't be there. If you still see it in the ReportViewer try `SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)`

Comment: @Jonnus setting the the Hidden property to true in this matrix leaves white space where the column should have been printed, therefore the size of the of the white space is equal to the size of the column.

Comment: @Oceans It shows in report viewer, html viewer, exported to pdf and word

Comment: Did you try to edit this width in the XML view of the rdlc ?

Comment: @RebamAsia1 can you share how you are setting the hidden property. If it's hidden properly there will be no white space

Comment: @Jonnus I highlight the column and in the properties pane I set the property "Hidden" under category "Visibility" to "True"

Comment: @Oceans I have tried but not succeeded

Comment: Is the gap in the lines of the Matrix? If so try setting the top and bottom borders of the column to the same as the ones around it.